# How can I load a JSON from an URL using unity for android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, internet-connection

I'm doing a Unity app for android that scans a QR code and displays a model with some buttons. The buttons displays the info of an event, said info is stored in a website. The way the app request the info is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WebTextLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    [Serializable]
    public class PlaceInfo
    {
        public string Titulo = "";
        public string Texto = "";
    }

    public string URL;
    public Text TituloUI;
    public Text TextoUI;

    public PlaceInfo placeInfo;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (Debug.isDebugBuild)
        {
            StartCoroutine(GetRequest(URL));

        }
    }
    IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            string jsonForm = uri;

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error loading");

            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    placeInfo = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlaceInfo>(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                    TituloUI.text = placeInfo.Titulo;
                    TextoUI.text = placeInfo.Texto;

                }
                catch
                {
                    Debug.Log("Error in connection");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

With this, the app works perfectly on the computer, using the editor, but when I build the apk and install it on my phone...it no longer works. The text never loads, I checked the Android manifest and everything seems ok:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="5" android:versionName="5.5">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Also in player settings, I checked "internet" as "require"

I don't know that i'm missing here, specially since the host i'm using is a paid one so I shouldn't have problems with limitations or stuff.

I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Please provide your logcat debug information

Comment: You need to catch the exception in catch block and log the message of the exception to understand the real issue.

Comment: From what I have, it's an error in the connection. It either doesn't get to the URL or can't download the JSON @0xBFE1A8

Comment: How do I do that?

@ChetanRanpariya